# Mysql trigger on Delete to multiple tables (also error 1235)

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-delete, cascading-deletes

I have 3 tables that are called:

- character_
- learned_skills
- skills

"character_" contains certain informations on a list of characters, while the table "skills" contrains a list of skills. 
the 3rd table is the list of the skills each character has learned.

However I want to able ones a character has been deleted from the character_ table, it also deletes the name of that character and the skills it has learned from the table "learned_skills".

I assume that a trigger is required in this situation. I know that the syntax is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name trigger_time trigger_event ON tbl_name FOR REACH ROW tigger_statement;
```

However I can't figure out how the trigger_statement should look like.

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_char_ AFTER DELETE ON character_ FOR REACH ROW trigger_statement
```

Is it enough with a sigle statement or does it require several statements and or cascade?

What would you do in this situation?

```
CREATE TABLE character_ ( 
  Name_             varchar (30) NOT NULL,
  Class             varchar (30),
  World_Type        varchar (15),
  Str               integer     ,
  WS                integer     ,               
  BS                integer     ,
  Fel               integer     ,
  Per               integer     ,
  Int_              integer     ,
  Agi               integer     ,
  WP                integer     ,
  Tough             integer     ,  
  PRIMARY KEY (Name_)           ,
  FOREIGN KEY (Class) REFERENCES Class(Class_name),
  FOREIGN KEY (World_Type) REFERENCES World_Type(Name_)     );

  CREATE TABLE Skills (
  SkillName         varchar (30) NOT NULL,
  Type_             varchar (30),
  Characteristic    varchar (30),
  Descriptor        varchar (30),
  PRIMARY KEY (SkillName)   );

  CREATE TABLE Learned_Skills ( 
  Character_Name    varchar (30) NOT NULL,
  Skill_Name        varchar (40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Character_Name,Skill_Name),
  FOREIGN KEY (Character_Name) REFERENCES character_(Name_),
  FOREIGN KEY (Skill_Name) REFERENCES Talents(TalentName)   );
```

---

UPDATE:

So I have had help to understand and make a DELETE trigger, but I have found out that need to create a multiple trigger on two tables, I know that its not possible to create a trigger on two with the same triggertime and event, but is there a way around it? What I need is the following:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER delete_char_ AFTER DELETE ON character_
FOR EACH ROW begin
DELETE FROM learned_skills
 WHERE learned_skills.Character_Name = old.Name_;
DELETE FROM learned_talents
 WHERE learned_talents.Character_Name = old.Name_;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

When I run this code I get error code:

> 1235, this version of mysql doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the samme action time and event for one table

Comment: Read [*Trigger Syntax and Examples*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) to know more on what trigger statement is.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed your update to your question.  You can't `CREATE` another trigger with the same name, you have to get rid of the old one first like so: `DROP TRIGGER delete_char_`, and then you will be able to `CREATE` the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what it would look like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_char_ AFTER DELETE ON character_
FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM learned_skills
    WHERE learned_skills.Character_Name = old.Name_;
```

You will need to replace `<field>` with whatever the primary key is of the `character_`.  This will delete anything from the learned_skills table that has the `<field>` of the `character_` being deleted.

Comment: And yes, a single statement will suffice, as the `DELETE` in the trigger statement will delete all rows that match the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks alot @dub stylee, but what if the two fields that are in that table, are primary keys (compound key)?

Comment: What are the fields in your `learned_skills` table, probably an ID for the `character_` and an ID for the `skill`, right?  You don't need to worry about the ID for the `skill`, as you are just deleting the rows that match the ID of the `character` being deleted.  If you want more specifics, go ahead and update your question with the specific fields you are wondering about.

Comment: the question has been updated and i have tried CREATE TRIGGER delete_char_ AFTER DELETE ON character_
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM learned_skills
    WHERE learned_skills.Name_ = old.Name_;
END; but get a syntax error in old.Name_ and END it says unexpected end

Comment: It looks like you need your WHERE clause to be `WHERE learned_skills.Character_Name = old.Name_;`

Comment: You may need to change the delimiter before you create the trigger.  Try `DELIMITER //` before you create the trigger and then add `//` after the `;` in the WHERE clause, then `DELIMITER ;` after the end of the trigger.  I will update my answer to show this.

Comment: @ dub stylee hmm okay, still syntax error at Name_ and END

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54227/discussion-between-dub-stylee-and-santelices).